# Standard Alert emails - what determines what is shown?

Tags: 2010, alert

When I create a standard alert, where does the format for that alert email come from?  How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find basics:

[Customizing Alert Templates in SharePoint Foundation 2010](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/Customizing%20Alert%20Templates%20in%20SharePoint%20Foundation%202010.aspx)

> SharePoint Foundation includes Pre-defined alert templates for e-mail
> and SMS messages
> Pre-defined Alert Template Location: %ProgramFiles%\Common
> Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML
> Email Template: AlertTemplates.xml SMS Template:
> AlertTemplates_SMS.xml
> Template includes information such as the format, contents and
> properties for the alert email and SMS messages.

Here you can find more details:

[Customizing Alert Notifications and Alert Templates in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20151108025726/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx)

And here you can find how to deploy custom alert templates by using VS 2010

[Creating custom list alert templates in SharePoint 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20161023144257/http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/08/15/creating-custom-list-alert-templates-in-sharepoint-2010/)